# Aiogram bot to answer my message in private chats but to reply my message in group chats

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

for telegram api, `Message.reply_html("Hello")` has quote which defaults to True in groups and False in private chats (https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a4/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.reply_html). Does aiogram have similar features?

Basically I want the bot to not reply my message in private chats but reply my message in group chats. This is because when creating discussion groups in channels, in order for the bot's reply to be shown in the discussion group, it has to reply to the message of the one who sent the message.

I know that aiogram has both message.reply which replies to the user regardless whether hes in a group or not and message.answer which answers the user regardless whether hes in a group or not too. Theres also a chat type filter which filters messages to private user vs messages to supergroup but to do that, I will need to repeat my code twice which is kinda pointless right when the only difference is a message and a reply?

I tried `message.reply('text', reply=False)` but that just removes the reply from both groups and private chat, which is equivalent to just `message.answer`. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my bad English. Aiogram has Filters, namely `aiogram.dispatcher.filters.ChatTypeFilter`, which inherits [`BounbdFilter`](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters.html). With which we can create customizable filters for our tasks. More information you can found in documentation. I wrote simple example of a bot that works only in a group. In private chat he doesn't works.

```py
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import BoundFilter
from aiogram import types

# filter.py
class IsGroup(BoundFilter):
    async def check(self, message: types.Message) -> bool:
        return message.chat.type in (
            types.ChatType.GROUP,
            types.ChatType.SUPER_GROUP,
        )


# handlers.py
@dp.message_handler(IsGroup(), content_types=types.ContentType.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS)
async def new_member(message: types.Message):
    members = ", ".join([m.get_mention(as_html=True) for m in message.new_chat_members])
    await message.reply(f"Hello, {members}.")
```

We are creating a chat and if we add new member bot wrote "Hello, {member}". And if you want use bot only in a chat you need add in the decorator `@dp.message_handler` *IsGroup()* And make it the **first argument**